# Selenium IDE - how to check if link is active

Tags: selenium

How do you check if the link is active or not in the given table of the page using the Selenium IDE commands?
The scenario is i will click one of the items in the left pane and the results will contain a table with links in the middle page. I will proceed to click the link in the result if the link is active, but if not I will choose another item on the left pane. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by link being active or not active?

Comment: how are inactive links defined? If they are still link elements, you can check for a href attribute. If they turn into plain text you might have a hard time since there's not straightforward way to do it